# Power Series about x=1

Tags: power-series

Find the first three terms of the power series solution to y''+xy=0, about x=1.  I know what I need to do, I'm just stuck on how to multiply x through the sum of an(x-1)^n.  I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

$$y''+xy=y''+(x-1+1)y=y''+(x-1)y+y.$$ Now expand each term and factor in the $(x-1)$ normally.